# How to open Download Languages of Google Settings from another app android programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services

I want open the Download Languages of Google Settings to the user can download his language to use the Speech Recognizer to Text offline.

Open the Download Languages like this (Kotlin):

```
try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_VOICE_INPUT_SETTINGS), 0)
}catch (ex : Exception){
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

And show to the user this page:
[image]

I don't know how to do this opening the Download Languages of Google Settings.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fun openSpeechRecognitionSettings() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    val components = arrayOf(ComponentName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.apps.gsa.settingsui.VoiceSearchPreferences"), ComponentName("com.google.android.voicesearch", "com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences"), ComponentName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences"), ComponentName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.apps.gsa.velvet.ui.settings.VoiceSearchPreferences"))
    for (componentName in components) {
        try {
            intent.component = componentName
            startActivity(intent)
            break
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            TODO("handle me")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it will open the **Settings** page, not the **Download Language** page.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you so much!